# How I do to fix this error with Transport apply?

Tags: python-3.x, zeep

I have an error with zeep python and Transport show me this message

```
AttributeError: 'Transport' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

My Code:

```
session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.proxies = {
    "https://myurl": "socks5://localhost:1080",
    "http://myurl": "socks5://localhost:1080",
}
client = Client(self.wsdl_cdc, Transport(session=session))
self.response = client.service.report(self.file)
```